# How can I add a image into uiwebview

Tags: ios, image, uiwebview

In iOS, I need to load a website in uiwebview and I want to add a local image at the beginning of the webpage.

I added < img src="logo.png"/> after < body > tag but it only showed a null pic(a small white box).

How can I load my local image as the src of the img inside the html? Thanks

Comment: <img src="logo.png"/> is added after <body>, but null pic is shown instead

Comment: solved, as the baseURL must be nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using relative paths or file: paths to refer to images does not work with UIWebView. Instead you have to load the HTML into the view with the correct baseURL:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
```

You can then refer to your images like this:

(from [uiwebview revisited](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/uiwebview-revisited))

Comment: try this, i'm sure this will work. NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"png"];
[myWebView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body><img src=\"file://%@\"></body></html>",path] baseURL:nil];

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the extact path of the image source see code below

```
NSString *imagePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image" ofType:@"png"];
imagePath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://%@",imagePath];

NSString *html=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body><img src=\"%@\"/></body></html>",imagePath];

[webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

Cheers.

Comment: @user3827922 You must be doing something wrong, can you do `NSLog(@"%@",imagePath);` and tell what you get?